# Table overflow in fieldset not working

Tags: css

I'm try put a table in `fieldset`, where table has a `width 2200px` fixed, and table parent (a div) has css property `overflow-x: auto; width: 100%`

Structure like this:

```
fieldset:
    div:
       table:
```

But scroll of div is not showing, how to can I fix this problem?

jsBin: http://jsbin.com/sazogamiha/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width: 100vw;` instead of `width: 100%;`.

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vayojub/1/edit)

```
#pai {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or you have to give `min-width: 0;` to `fieldset`. `fieldset` has  `min-width: -webkit-min-content;` by default so you override that.

```
fieldset {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/boteye/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you so mcuh! set `min-width: 0px` in `fieldset` is solver my problem, but why occur this?

Comment: @Lai32290 You are welcome. That is browser default(`min-width: -webkit-min-content;`). You can use [reset css](http://cssreset.com/) to override all default browser rules.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you're using the comma (",") instead of the semicolon (";") to separate css properties?

About widths.
Some tags do not work well for your issue, and one of those is fieldset

Try this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <fieldset>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>...</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS

```
div.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
div.container {
  overflow-x: auto; 
  width: 90%;
}
table {
  width: 2000px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, is my fail about comma